# samsung nvme ssd write errors on gpt restore, even with 100% available_spare

Tags: linux, gpt, smart, nvme, gdisk

i have an samsung nvme ssd with corrupted gpt information. Nevertheles live boot running gdisk reported, that the on-disk gpt backup is clean and can be used to restore the main gpt information.

So fine, i run the restore and get write error during restoring the main gpt information. First it looks like hardware failure, so i looked into the nvme  smart-log, but this did seem okay. I am only at 18% of ssd lifetime and i have 100% of available spare. Nevertheless, whenever i try to write the main gpt to the disk, the number of media_errors and num_error_log_entries increase.

Did i misunderstand something here? As far as i know the ssd should replace defect sectors with spare ones, when it fails to write to those. But this mechanism seems to not work, since i have problematic sectors but 100% available spare? Can i enforce the samsung nvme disk to replace problemativ sectors with spare ones?

[image]

Comment: It says inside the text that it could be damaged. Given that you've tried several times, i think that's the only cause.

Comment: @NiallJones okay, i think this is reasonable, but then how do i detect if the nvme is really damaged in way where switching with available spare sectors does not work?

Comment: Check if the disk has inadvertently become read-only. You might be able to reverse  it.

Comment: @StarCat sadly i found no way to get the status of the readonly flag or to set this property for the oem drive Samsung MZVPV256HDGL-00000 with Firmware  BXW7300Q